# Por que na linguagem C array[6] é igual a 6[array]?

Tags: array, c, ponteiro

Nota: Pergunta que vi no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a), mas achei interessante de colocar aqui (porque ainda não temos muitas perguntas de C):

Porque na linguagem C, esses código imprime "verdadeiro"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int reais[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) reais[i] = i;
    int num = reais[6];
    int num2 = 6[reais];
    if(num == num2) printf("verdadeiro"); else printf("falso");
    return 0;
}
```

Nota: Compilei isso com C99, ele NÃO COMPILA no C89 (porque não pode declarar variável dentro do for() )

Quem quiser pode copiar e colar isso no [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) para ver compilar e rodar.

Comment: Legal. Se ela for muito parecida com a original, seria bom colocar um link para lá para dar o crédito.

Comment: Uma observação quanto a declaração de variáveis dentro do for(). Em ANSI-C, variáveis só podem ser declarada após chaves "{" (braces). Nesta caso seu escopo é limitado na área onde foi declarada.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Referenciando o standard do C:

> ## 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
>
> **Constraints**
>   One of the expressions shall have type "pointer to complete object *type*", the other
>   expression shall have integer type, and the result has type "*type*".
>
> **Semantics**
>   A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]`
>   is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary + operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an integer, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th
>   element of `E1` (counting from zero).

O relevante é que ao escrever `a[b]`, um dos valores deve ser um ponteiro (ou uma array que decaia a um ponteiro) e outro deve ser um tipo integral. Não é especificado nenhuma restrição sobre qual deve ser o que. O segundo ponto é que `a[b]` é equivalente a `*(a+b)`. Assim temos:

```
a[b] = *(a+b) = *(b+a) = b[a]
```

O mesmo pode ser aplicado também a strings literais, já que são `const char[]`:

```
char M = 4["Ola Mundo"];
```

Embora essa sintaxe seja perfeitamente válida e legal, não é boa prática acessar arrays invertendo os operandos assim. A leitura fica bastante não intuitiva e não há vantagens.

Comment: Oxe, resposta sensacional, melhor do que a em inglês. Não imaginei de usar char dessa forma! É até uma sintaxe legal :P

Comment: +1 pelo `const char[]`

Comment: +1 pelo 'intervendo' ao invés de invertendo

Comment: O que significa o 4 em char M = 4["Ola Mundo"]; ?

Answer (score 9):

Quando você define uma array em C o operador [] define o seguinte:

```
reais[10] == *(reais + 10)
```

Logo `reais[10]` vai ser `*(reais + 10)`
e `10[reais]` vai ser `*(10 + reais)`

`reais` é um endereço de memória, já `reais[10]` é o endereço de memória + 10 posições a sua frente. É assim que funciona um vetor ele armazena um ponteiro com o nome + posições.E em matemática básica sabemos que:

```
reais + 10 = 10 + reais
```

Fonte: [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a)

Comment: +1 por citar a fonte

Answer (score 3):

Bom... A primeira coisa que temos que ter e mente aqui é que um vetor, nada mais é que um ponteiro para uma determinada região de memória.

Quando a linha de código, `int reais[10]`, é executada, são alocados 10 inteiros e o endereço do primeiro item é armazenado, apenas.

Quando você acessa uma determinada posição do vetor, `reais[6]` por exemplo, o que realmente acontece é que o programa pega o endereço do ponteiro, ou seja, do primeiro valor (elemento) e soma com o offset que você passou vezes o tamanho do dado. Isso é, o endereço de memória efetivamente acessado é `reais + 6*tamanho de um inteiro` (a multiplicação pelo tamanho do dado é feita implicitamente, de acordo com o tipo do vetor definido), onde reais é o endereço do primeiro elemento do vetor. Em outras palavras, o que acontece é: `*(reais + 6)`. Veja que o operador de desreferenciação é utilizado.

Dito isso, quando você utiliza a notação `6[reais]`, o que acontece é exatamente o mesmo que descrevi acima. Só que agora você muda a ordem da soma entre o endereço e o offset, ou seja, `*(6 + reais)`.

Como a adição é uma operação comutativa, o resultado é o mesmo e por isso acessamos o mesmo endereço de memória. Logo, `reais[6] == 6[reais]`.

Isso ocorre porque [] é um operador (tanto que em C++ você pode sobrecarregá-lo).