# Qual a diferença entre essas formas de indexar um ponteiro para array de structs em c?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, ponteiro

Existe alguma diferença no uso dessas 3 declarações?

```
void addCliente(struct cliente *dadosCliente){
    dadosCliente[k].nome="oi";
    (*(dadosCliente+k)).nome="oi";
    (dadosCliente+k)->nome="oi";
}
void main(){
    struct cliente clientes[1000];
    addCliente(clientes);
}
```

Comment: Como é a estrutura utilizada? `nome` é um ponteiro, certo?

Comment: Nenhum diferença, exceto pela legibilidade. Todas terão o mesmo efeito.

Comment: A pergunta é bacana, mas não se trata exatamente de "declaração" (ou mesmo "atribuição") de strings, e sim sobre formas de acessar elementos de uma struct, não é? Nesse caso, eu sugiro editar ao menos o título para tornar mais claro.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As três formas de acessar uma struct em uma array são equivalentes.

- `a[b]` é igual a `(*(a+b))` [(mais detalhes)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2730/429)
- `(*a).c` é igual a `a->c`

Portanto:

- `(*(a+b)).c` é `(a+b)->c`
- `(*(a+b)).c` é `a[b].c`

Comment: e teria alguma mais eficiente que outra?

Comment: Não. São exatamente iguais do ponto de vista semântico. Apenas formas diferentes de dizer a mesma coisa.

Comment: @user2984406: Compiladores hoje em dia são muito bons em otimizar código, muitas vezes mudando bastante a estrutura dele. Acessar um array pelo índice em um loop bem definido permite que o compilador possa fazer essas otimizações mais facilmente, além de deixar o código muito mais legível pra quem for fazer a manutenção depois.